# How to open webpage in WebBrowser control in a loop

Tags: c#, .net, loops, webbrowser-control

I am using a `WebBrowser` control in my application.

I have URLs of websites in a list, and I want **to open them one by one in my web browser control using C#.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go:

```
List<string> hyperlinks = new List<string>();

foreach (string str in hyperlinks)
{

mybrowser.Navigate(str);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

WebBrowser.Navigate(); ?

Answer (score 0):

foreach (string str in hyperlinks) works however the problem is the answer won't give you the result you want.

1. You need to wait for each document to complete first before you navigate to the next document.  The foreach statement will load each document but the only document that will fully load will be the last document.
2. You need to ingore the Java Script errors as this creates numerous exceptions in the WebBrowser component.